# Mac App crashes when I add a Distribution Profile

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode5.1

I've created a Mac App for Mavericks that uses MapKit. It works fine during development and testing on Xcode 5.1. Now I'd like to submit it to the App Store and I need a Distribution Profile which I've created successfully. Trouble is, as soon as I add it to my project, the app doesn't run anymore - it crashes every time without fail with this error message:

[image]

When I change back to "no provisioning profile", or to the profile that Xcode created during development, the app runs again.

My question: Is this expected behaviour, or will the app be rejected by the review team? I know that iOS apps don't run with their distribution profiles, but I'm new to Mac Development. Any insights into this way too complex topic are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app was approved - and the crash was indeed no issue for the app review team.

I had a chat with Apple about this who were kind enough to call me back and explain the issue. Looks like this phenomenon is "kind of" expected behaviour: Mac Apps may or may not crash when run with a Distribution Profile.

To avoid this problem, we can add both a Development AND a Distribution Profile to our app, without one having to replace the other. This was news to me. Had I however opened my tired eyes a bit wider  I would have perhaps spotted the little disclosure triangle myself:

[image]

Perhaps this helps those with the same issue.